# how to fix the below regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex which checks if the start of the string is either a ,-' (hyphen, comma or apostrophe.). I have the below regex

```
'^[^,'-]'
```

But it seems like its not working. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: same issue. it returns true for any character now in my code

Answer (score 2):

Remove the caret (`^`) from the character class as it means NOT i.e. by placing it in the character class, you are saying, *NOT comma, apostrophe or hyphen*.

```js
let r=/^[,'-]/
console.log(r.test('a'))
console.log(r.test(','))
console.log(r.test('^'))
console.log(r.test('-'))
console.log(r.test('('))
```

Comment: for me the third test should also be false